# How to make gradle build script constants available in the built code?

Tags: gradle, dry

I am building and running some unit tests from within a gradle build script. The tests need to access some resources located in `gradle_project_dir/src/test/resources/fixtures` which in `gradle.build` logic can be expressed as

```
apply plugin: 'java'

// ... 

File fixturesDir = new File(sourceSets.test.resources.srcDirs[0], "fixtures")
```

**What is the best way of pointing the test source to the file as seen in build.gradle?**

I want to avoid hard-coding the path in the tests to keep them [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

The cleanest solution that currently comes to my mind is to make the gradle build script first build some `.jar` with `BuildConstants` class or similar which will contain the `fixturesDir` file and make the tests source depend on it.

Another option is to make both the build script and the tests depend on some external .jar (possibly built with yet another gradle build script).

Something tells me there should be a simpler way, though.

Comment: `SomeTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/fixtures/foo")`. The point of the resources directory is that the resources it contains end up in the runtime classpath of the tests.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I want to share some string instead of a file? E.g. I want for both the build script and the built code to know some system-dependent string value? Put it in a system environment variable? And if I have many such values? Add as properties in a textual properties file added to the resources dir? If you would post a full answer I could make the question formally answered.

Comment: Yes, a system property or a properties file containing placeholders that are replaced at build time by gradle are valid solutions.

Comment: Hmm, actually, this doesn't entirely solve the problem. The directory path is now DRYied up, but the name of the accessed resource still has to be hard-coded in two places: in the build script and in the source code accessing it ;(